# SharePoint 2013 Reporting Service Integration mode

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

I face a difficult problem that I don't understand.

What I have:

- SharePoint 2013 Enterprise
- SQL Server 2012 with all installed SP features, but configured in NATIVE mode.
- Both on the same server

So we decided to change SSRS mode to SP integration mode.

1. Problem: During configuring RS there is no option to create database in SP integrated mode, like it was in SQL 2008 and SP 2010
2. I created "SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application" and "SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application Proxy" in Administration of SP. But it doesn't work

   > The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable ....:32843/d308605809d6497aa00c8f49033cb45d/ReportingWebService.svc'.

   And I know why. Because this path doesn't exists in IIS. There is no such sub folder in services of SP. Databases(TempDB, Alerting..) during configuration was successfully created.

Question is what I am doing wrong?